# How to confirm state change caused by a transaction

Tags: transactions

I'm trying to verify what happened in a transaction, to my understanding the only guaranteed way would be to monitor state change. The other options I've looked into are the combinations of input data/logs data/transaction traces. To my understanding, these don't have guarantees to provide a complete and credible picture of what happened in a transaction.

Does anyone know a way to determine how Ethereum's state changed after the completion of a transaction, or does anyone know a credible way to determine what happened in a transaction?

Comment: If you run your own archive node (or hire one) you can replay any transaction you like with tracing enabled, which tells you every single EVM opcode that executed

Comment: @user253751 thank you! looking into this now

Comment: you can avoid running archival node if you implement a very robust tracing mechanism. You have only 128 blocks keeping state changes on the tail of the blockchain, so if your processes get a downtime and it lasts for more than 128 blocks, you will lose the state changes (there will be a "hole" in your data and you won't be able to trace)

Comment: you "confirm" the state changes by getting a Receipt of the trnasaction and checking the `Status` field, this is how it is guaranteed that all changes are permanent. You don't need to verify every state change individually

Answer (score 1):

Any smart contract state is publicly available on any EVM chain. You just need to read it after the transaction executed, for instance:

```js
 const value256 = await ethers.provider.getStorageAt(contractAddress, slot);
```

You just need to figure out what slots you want to read and decode them afterwards.

You can find ideas about computing slots and decoding several types [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/solidity-storage-variables-with-ethers-js-ca3c7e2c2a64)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! looking into this now

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped in your problem. Thanks.